# Cannot receive message sent from main process to renderer process in Electron

Tags: electron

I'm sending a message from the main to the renderer process.

In the main process, I'm doing this:

```js
const ipcMain = require('electron').ipcMain;

ipcMain.on('asynchronous-message', function(event, arg) {
   console.log('m i here');
   event.sender.send('asynchronous-reply', 'pong');
});
```

In the renderer script, I'm doing this:

```js
const ipcRenderer = require('electron').ipcRenderer;

ipcRenderer.on('asynchronous-reply', function(event, arg) {
    console.log('In renderer again');
});
```

However, it seems like the message is not received in the renderer process. What am I missing?

Comment: Is 'm i here' being printed in the main process? Could you also include the code you use to initiate the messaging chain? Are you doing something like: ipcRenderer.send('asynchronous-message', 'ping'); from the renderer process?

Answer (score 8):

Thanks. I finally got around to understanding the concept. The whole idea that I was missing was to initiate the messaging chain from the renderer process. Actually I had two renderer processes: html 1, html 2. The idea was to populate html 2 based on contents in html 1.

Below is what worked for me

**Main.js**

```js
ipcMain.on('Request-from-SOR-Page', function(event, arg) {
    var nomenclature = arg;

    ipcMain.on('Request-frm-AOR-Page', function(event, arg) {
        event.sender.send('Response-To-AOR-Page', nomenclature);
    });
});
```

**Script for html 1**

```js
const ipcRenderer = require('electron').ipcRenderer;
ipcRenderer.send('Request-from-SOR-Page', aor.nomenclature);
```

**Script for html 2**

```js
var ipcRenderer = require("electron").ipcRenderer;

ipcRenderer.send('Request-frm-AOR-Page');
ipcRenderer.on('Response-To-AOR-Page', function(event, data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

My conclusion is that in order to communicate between the main and the renderer process, the renderer needs to initiate the messaging or use `webContents.send` if there is a standalone message initiated from the main process.

Please correct if my assumption is true.

Answer (score 6):

You're never actually sending anything. You're just registering a listener in both the Main and Renderer processes.

- To send a message from Renderer to Main, use [`ipcRenderer.send`](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/ipc-renderer#ipcrenderersendchannel-args).
- To send a message from Main to Renderer, use [`BrowserWindow#webContents.send`](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/web-contents#contentssendchannel-args).

Answer (score 1):

IPC in electron works by registering event listeners that trigger asynchronously. With

```
ipcMain.on('asynchronous-message', function(event, arg) {
  console.log('m i here');
  event.sender.send('asynchronous-reply', 'pong');
});
```

you are registering a listener (asynchronous-message) executing a function when triggered.

```
ipcRenderer.on('asynchronous-reply', function(event, arg) {
  console.log('In renderer again');
});
```

is defining another listener, and it will log a message once it gets triggered. To trigger it, simply add

```
ipcRenderer.send('Request-from-SOR-Page', aor.nomenclature);
```

to your browser windows JS.

`.send(target, payload)`

is a method specific to the ipcRenderer object which will trigger the target ipc listener in ipcMain with the payload specified.